# Set next Notification scheduleLocalNotification Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, ios, notifications, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium appcelerator to use `scheduleLocalNotification` I am getting it perfectly fine.I just want to know is there a way i can set the next `scheduleLocalNotification` on receive of first notification.Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure if you aim for that, but you can add:

```
Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('notification', function(e) {
    // Trigger the next notification
});
```

which triggers, whenever a local notification is received.
In it you could check, if it's your local notification and if so, schedule a new one.

For further information about the 'notification' event try:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-event-notification

Comment: `Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('notification', function(e) {});` This notification event is only fired when app is in foreground any idea which listener is called when the app is in background and notification is received. ? Thanks for you help.

Comment: None. Your app will receive the notification after being activated again. There is this 10min rule from apple where apps can't stay active in background forever. If your user is capable of opening the app every 10mins or so you could try using a backgroundService (see: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService) and invoke the notification there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'localnotificationaction'`listener instead of `'notification'`to call the app in background.
After that u can interact with notification action like :

```
Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('notification', function(e) {
       if (e.category == "DOWNLOAD_CONTENT" && e.identifier == "ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER") {
                    alert('start download');
                }

                // Reset the badge value
                if (e.badge > 0) {
                    // reset send
                }
       });
```

Comment: Hey, welcome on Stack Overflow! Thanks for that answer it's great, but please use quotes when referring to relevant comments of OP or other users. They get lost sometimes and pasting their contents into the answer preserves the value of the answer. Not only question authors read the answers. Anyway thanks! :))